# lubridate with_tz not working with dplyr group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm trying to convert a series of UTC times into local times given a vector of time zones.

```
test = tibble(time = c(as_datetime('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
                       as_datetime('2019-01-01 01:00:00'),
                       as_datetime('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
                       as_datetime('2019-01-01 01:00:00')), 
              tz = c('EST','EST','Asia/Hong_Kong','Asia/Hong_Kong'))
```

I can't seem to get with_tz to recognize the timezone variable.  Nothing is converted.

```
 test %>% group_by(tz) %>% mutate(localtime = with_tz(time, tz[1]))

  time                tz             localtime          
  <dttm>              <chr>          <dttm>             
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 EST            2019-01-01 00:00:00
2 2019-01-01 01:00:00 EST            2019-01-01 01:00:00
3 2019-01-01 00:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 00:00:00
4 2019-01-01 01:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 01:00:00
```

I tried getting evaluting tz[1] first but groups are ignored. (probably as expected)

```
test %>% group_by(tz) %>% mutate(localtime = with_tz(time, !!tz[1]))

   time                tz             localtime          
  <dttm>              <chr>          <dttm>             
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 EST            2018-12-31 19:00:00
2 2019-01-01 01:00:00 EST            2018-12-31 20:00:00
3 2019-01-01 00:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2018-12-31 19:00:00
4 2019-01-01 01:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2018-12-31 20:00:00
```

I tried rowwise but it uses "Asia/Hong_Kong" for all timezones.  (did not expect this)

```
test %>% rowwise %>% mutate(localtime = with_tz(time, tz))

 time                tz             localtime          
<dttm>              <chr>          <dttm>             
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 EST            2019-01-01 08:00:00
2 2019-01-01 01:00:00 EST            2019-01-01 09:00:00
3 2019-01-01 00:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 08:00:00
4 2019-01-01 01:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 09:00:00
```

Can someone explain what is going on please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A column is an atomic vector, i.e. the elements are of the same type and have the same attributes, so you can't set the timezones for each element individually. You can, however, put heterogeneous elements with different attributes in lists. For example, you could do something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

test_nested <- test %>%
    mutate(tz_group = tz) %>% 
    nest(-tz_group, .key = tz_times) %>%
    mutate(tz_times = map(tz_times,
                          ~ mutate(., localtime = with_tz(time, tz[1]))
                      )
           )
```

Which returns a dataframe with a list-column, each element of which contains times with different timezones:

```r
test_nested

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  tz_group       tz_times    
  <chr>          <list>      
1 EST            <tibble [3]>
2 Asia/Hong_Kong <tibble [3]>
```

The obvious downside is that the values are hidden, but you can make them visible by `pull`ing the list column:

```r
test_nested %>% pull(tz_times)
```

Which returns:

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  time                tz    localtime          
  <dttm>              <chr> <dttm>             
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 EST   2018-12-31 19:00:00
2 2019-01-01 01:00:00 EST   2018-12-31 20:00:00

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  time                tz             localtime          
  <dttm>              <chr>          <dttm>             
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 08:00:00
2 2019-01-01 01:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 09:00:00
```

Alternatively you can `spread` the list-column elements to separate columns and `unnest`:

```r
test_nested %>% 
    spread(tz_group, tz_times) %>%
    unnest() %>% 
    select(-starts_with("time"))
```

Which returns a wide dataframe with timezone labels next to the the datetimes:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  tz             localtime           tz1   localtime1         
  <chr>          <dttm>              <chr> <dttm>             
1 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 08:00:00 EST   2018-12-31 19:00:00
2 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 09:00:00 EST   2018-12-31 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a single column can only have one tzone attribute.  So I couldn't get the localtime time column to hold datetime objects with different timezones.  This is circumvented by converting the column into a string.

```
test %>% group_by(tz) %>% mutate(localtime = strftime(time, tz = tz[1]))

 time                tz             localtime          
<dttm>              <chr>          <chr>              
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 EST            2018-12-31 19:00:00
2 2019-01-01 01:00:00 EST            2018-12-31 20:00:00
3 2019-01-01 00:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 08:00:00
4 2019-01-01 01:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong 2019-01-01 09:00:00
```